# Coldfusion - Checking for all lowercase or uppercase

Tags: regex, ms-access

I have been given the daunting task of sifting through a database of over 30,000 registrants and correcting the letter casing of names and addresses where needed.  I am trying to write a program that will search for names and addresses in our database that are either all lowercase or all uppercase and output these mishaps in a webpage for me to review and correct more efficiently.  I was informed that I could utilize Regular Expressions to find fields that adhere to my criteria, only I am new to programming and I am unfamiliar with the syntax of RegEx.

If anyone could provide me with some pointers as how to use RegEx to query for these inconsistencies, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: We are using Microsoft Access

Answer (score 1):

[`strComp`](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/StrComp-Function-a9a4531e-3b2a-4218-b139-f7442bc10b96) should work

```
SELECT col 
FROM table  
WHERE strComp(col, lcase(col), 0) = 0 --all lower case
  OR strComp(col, ucase(col), 0) = 0 --all upper case
```

The first two arguments are the columns to compare. The 3rd argument says to do a binary comparison. If the two strings are equal 0 is returned.

Comment: Mr. Busche, 
Is strComp used to compare two existing strings in my database?  I need to evaluate each string independently and determine if they either contain all uppercase letters or all lowercase letters.

Comment: @DetentionClox I've updated my answer so the query returns all upper case and all lower case matches.

Answer (score 0):

How will you accurately correct the data?  If you see a last name of "MACGUYVER" should it change to Macguyver or MacGuyver?  If you see a last name of "DE LA HOYA" will it become de la Hoya, De La Hoya, or something else?  This task seems a bit dangerous.

If your plan is basically to just do initial capitalization then I suggest that you run an update first before doing any manual review.

You could run something like this to change your name fields to initial capital letters:

```
update yourTable
set lname = StrConv(lname,3)
where StrComp(lname, StrConv(lname,3), 0) <> 0
and StrComp(mid(lname,2,len(lname)), lcase(mid(lname,2,len(lname))), 0) = 0;
```

Where "lname" above is your last name column, for example.
The above would have to be run for each name field.

Note that this will not update names that legitimately have multiple capital letters, like MacGuyver or O'Connor, which need manual review.
Also note that it *will* update last names that start with van, von, de la, and others that may intentionally be lowercase.

You could then query for just the names that need manual review, which I assume will be a much smaller subset:

```
select *
from yourTable
where StrComp(lname, StrConv(lname,3), 0) <> 0;
```

Addresses are tougher.  To find just those that are either all lowercase or all uppercase you can do this:

```
select *
from yourTable
where strComp(address1, lcase(address1), 0) = 0;

select *
from yourTable
where strComp(address1, ucase(address1), 0) = 0;
```

Obviously this won't catch address lines like "123 New YORK AveNUE".

Consider asking for permission to just set all address values to uppercase.
You'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: if I were doing it, I would do the 1st pass you suggested - but would also flag those records (that my 1st pass modified) with another field as also needing a manual review.  And back it all up first!